# How do I add a word before the last character in the last occurrence of a string with sed?

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to use sed to find the last occurrence of a string in a file, then add something into the "middle" of that string. I only want to search for a portion of the string, because the whole string may be different (the string I am trying to add to is a variable that can have different values). I always want to add before the last character in the string.

For Example:

```
Thing=name
Word=value
Stuff=tree
Word=anotherValue!
This=that
```

I want to add a word before the last character in the last occurrence of "Word=":

```
Thing=name
Word=value
Stuff=tree
Word=anotherValueOkay!
This=that
```

I know that `tac | sed <?> | tac` is how to handle the last occurrence of the string, but how do I add a word to that last occurrence of the string, before the last character in the string?

Comment: The simplest way: Reverse lines in file, match the first occurence with sed, reverse lines in file. If you ask specifically about sed, you might want to add `sed` as a tag to the question. Or is any bash-list solution acceptable? Yes, tac | sed | tac. I think it is do-able  in sed only.

Comment: So use something like tac, then sed, then tac? I was hoping for specifically sed. I'll make sure to add that tag, thanks. Alright, I'll try that, thank you.

Comment: @KamilCuk I edited my question to be more clear with what I am attempting to do. tac <filename> | sed <?> | tac <filename> is how to find the last occurrence of the string, but how do I add to that string in the way that I described above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kamil Cuk's answer shows, doing this *only* with sed is pretty difficult.

If you can use other tools in cooperation with sed, it's a lot simpler.

Here's an example:

Get the line number of the final appearance of `Word=`. The `=` operation prints the line number of the matching row(s) to stdout. Then use `tail` to keep only the last line number.

```
line=$(sed -n -e '/^Word=/=' sample.txt | tail -1)
```

Then use that line number in a subsequent command, to apply the substitution only to that line:

```
sed -e ${line}'s/.$/!&/' sample.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My struggle is that I don't know what the whole line is; just the beginning. Because of this, I can't substitute the whole line because I don't know what the whole line is.

Comment: The substitution I show above only changes the last character, inserting a "!" before it. The rest of the line, whatever it is, is left alone.

Comment: Alright, so when I try using this it all works fine until the substitution. Instead of adding the desired string before the last character, it adds the desired string to the end of the string.

Comment: Apologies, I was mistaken; this works as intended. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The `bash` script with `sed` script embedded below:

```
cat <<EOF |
Thing
Wod
Stuff1
Wod
Stuff2
EOF
sed -n '
  # omit all the initial lines until
  # Wod is encountered
  /^Wod$/!{
    p
    d
  }

  : a
  {
    # Hold the line
    H
    # read next line
    n
    # if its the Wod line
    /Wod/{
      # that means that the Wod in hold space
      # is not the last one
      # print the hold space as it is and remove it
      x
      s/^\n//
      p
      s/.*//
      x
    }
    # if this is the last line
    ${
      # that means the Wod in hold space is the last one
      x
      G
      s/^\n//
      # So substitute it for Word
      s/^Wod/Word/
      # and print
      p
      # and quit
      q
    }

    # loop
    b a
  }
'
```

produces the following output:

```
Thing
Wod
Stuff1
Word
Stuff2
```

The explanation is in comments. When writing comments I assumed the reader is acquainted with pattern/hold space concepts in `sed`.

I think the first part about just printing initiall lines until "Wod" can be removed/merged with rest of code by checking if there is already a Wod word in hold space, but it works as it is.

@edit For updated examples in OPs question that would be:

```
cat <<EOF |
Thing=name
Word=value
Stuff=tree
Word=anotherValue!
This=that
EOF
# this is the same script as above
# only comments are removed and different regexes are used to substitue and match the line. `Wod` is matched above, here `^Word=` is matched, etc.
sed -n -E '/^Word=/!{p;d;};:a;H;n;/^Word=/{x;s/^\n//;p;s/.*//;x;};${x;G;s/^\n//;s/^(Word=[^\n]*)/Word=anotherValueOkay!/;p;q;};ba'
```

I match against `^Word=`, dunno what's intended pattern is should be here. Then I substitute the `Word=[^\n]*`, ie. `Word=` part up until the end of line with the `Word=AnotherValueOkay!` line.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but I'm not well-versed with sed.

Is this script assuming that the next instance of "Wod" will be exactly 1 line after the first one?

Also, if I'm not mistaken, the last instance of "Wod" is being replaced with "Word", right? My issue is that the last occurrence of the string I want to find will always begin with the same few characters, but the whole string will not always contain all the same characters every time. Am I still able to substitute if I don't know what the whole contents of the string will be?

Comment: 1. No it does not assume that. You can have as many lines between "Wod"s, they should end up in hold space. 2. Well, that's the goal. 3. So change the regex. The second snipped for example uses `^Word=[^\n]*` to match from the beginning to the end of line. Notice, match up-until `\n` newlnie chaaracter, doing. Because multiple lines are loaded into pattern space, doing ex. `Word=.*` will match all lines. Also `\n` is a gnu extension, for posix sed use a literal newline in pattern match inside `s` command.

Comment: [tutorialspoint](http://tpcg.io/WNdVEV)  Seems to work for multiple lines between "Wod"s and to substitute the whole last "Wod" line to something else.

Comment: So this will allow me to add "Okay" to "Word=anotherValue!" even though I don't know what the "anotherValue" part will actually be? The reason why I'm confused here is because  the "anotherValue" part of the line may be different each time this script is called. Thus, how can we replace the last instance of "Word=" with a whole new line that has the new word added in, if we don't know what the whole line actually is?

Comment: You just match the line against `^Word=[^\n]*`... It seems like you need to brush up your regexes. I would advise to start with [regex crosswords](https://regexcrossword.com/), that's one cool way to learn it. Then move up to the great [sed introduction](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) to understand pattern and hold space. sed is turing complete, but any task that involves working on more then a single line at a time is not worth the time and fastly becomes very, very complicated in sed.

Comment: Alright, I will give those links a visit. Thank you for taking the time to help answer this question, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -zE 's/(.*Word[^\n]*)([^\n])/\1Okay\2/' file
```

Slurp the file into memory using the `-z` option and utilise greed by using `.*` in the regexp to find the last word beginning `Word`.

If `Word` must be at the beginning of a line, use:

```
sed -zE 's/(.*\nWord[^\n]*)([^\n])/\1Okay\2/' file
```

An alternative:

```
sed -nE '/(.*Word[^\n]*)([^\n])/{h;:a;$x;$s//\1Okay\2/p;n;//x;//p;//!H;ba};p' file
```